# The arabic input parameter passed as like a junk input JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We were using *JasperReports 4.6.0* and *Java 1.6* to generate the *PDF* reports. It was working fine for parameters with text on English. If I pass the Arabic input parameter the input parameter
passed as like a junk character hence I couldn't fetch the recordset. The same was working when I use *JasperReports 3.7.6* and *Java 1.5*

My code:

```
JasperPrint print = null;
Runtime run = null;
String strJasperFile = "E:/DailyWork/FEB-2013/report2.jasper";
String strOutputFile = "E:/DailyWork/FEB-2013/report2.xls";
String printtime="";
Connection con = getSqlConnection();        
HashMap mpDetailSp = new HashMap(); 
mpDetailSp.put("parameter1", "B المهمات");
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(strJasperFile, mpDetailSp, con);           
JRExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, strOutputFile);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Could you please advise me how to sort it out this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not being the an expert in Jasper I can suppose that the problem is in the text encoding. I performed a short search and found this resource: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/misc/tools/jasper/java.html

Please take a look in the template example and pay attention on line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on top of the file. Does your file `report2.jasper` contain such line? Check it and include it if it is missing.

Additionally add line

`exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");`

I hope now all will work.

Comment: I'm trying your solution and let u know the results asap

Comment: Sorry It couldn't help me out. still it passes a junk character

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found out the solution for this problem. It was encoding setting in the Java 1.6 JVM. I had set the environment variable as like below to sort it out the problem

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

It was resolved my problem. The input was given by the another forum post in statck overflow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/770927

I thank to Edward Grech, He explained obvious reason and solution in the above post.